# Why is it necessary to declare a string's length in an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, declaration

Why can the compiler know how much strings there are but not how much chars they contain?
For example, this works:

```
char songs[][30]{ 
  "A string", 
  "Another string" 
};
```

And this one doesn't:

```
char songs[][]{ 
  "A string", 
  "Another string" 
};
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: Do you mean a string array such as `{ "short", "longer", "extremely long filler" };`? This is an array of `char *` and not `char x[3][22]`.

Comment: There are two different questions here.  The title question is asking about an 'array of strings'; while the inside question is asking about an 'array of char'.  Patkoala, perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer In C, an array of `char` is often called a string since C has no string type.

Comment: Some might say 'C null-terminated strings are total crap', I couldn't possibly comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're fine with constant strings, then you don't.

```
const char *strings[] = {
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
    "quux",
};
```

The only time when you'd need to give it the length of the strings is if you were trying to make a two dimensional array of `char`s, like

```
char strings[][5] = {
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
    "quux",
};
```

C can guess the outermost dimension, but the items in the array have to be complete types, and an array of `char` of unknown length is not complete, but both `char[5]` and `const char *` are.

Comment: Thank you very much!
And I'm so sorry, the next time I'll clarify a lot more the question